# Why is the dock icon for ukuu so distorted?

Tags: 18.04, icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I have recently downloaded `ukuu` aka *Ubuntu Kernel Upgrade Utility* and when I install it and then search for it in the start menu I see this:

[image]

But when I open it then the icon in the dock looks as follows:

[image]

Why?

Comment: I presume you're using the Papirus icon theme. Try reporting this to the developers of the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

That because StartupWMClass option is missing in desktop-file. To fix that run a few commands:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/ukuu.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
echo 'StartupWMClass=ukuu-gtk' >> ~/.local/share/applications/ukuu.desktop
```